# Find number of triangles.

Tags: geometry

This is an extremely basic question posed to my brother in fifth standard and i was only able to find $20$ triangles in this figure however the answer according to the answer key was 24.
$Side -1: 12   $
$Side -2: 6   $
$Side -3: 2    $
Is there any way to conclusively prove that there are only 20 triangles?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $12$ "simple" triangles. Each peak belongs to one of six size-two triangles and there are two size-three triangles. So the $20$ seems to be correct.

An alternative approach: Each triangle is bounded by a horizontal straight line, an ascending $60^\circ$ line and a descending $60^\circ$ line. Since there are three lines of each type, we'd arrive at $3\cdot3\cdot 3$ triangles. However, the seven points of intersection (center and vertices of hexagon) fail to produce a triangle. $27-7=20$.

Comment: Neat proof!$\,\,$

Answer (score 2):

I see $12$ with a side of $1$, $6$ with a side of $2$ and $2$ with a side of $3$ for $20$.  It would be good to post that in your question, so if we disagreed on a specific size, we could point out where it disagreement lies.

Comment: Yes that is what i also figured.Sorry for not posting it.